# multiple kendo grids using one script

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I'm loading multiple partial views into the same cshtml page. All goes well until they need to use the scripts. As i'm using code like

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selected = grid.selected();
```

This code works fine with one grid, but starts showing issues when multiple grids are in place. The problem is that "#grid" is a reference to the name of the kendo grid. Is there a way to make this dynamic so it can be used by multiple grids?

I think the same problem would occur when there are multiple grids in the same page as it can't distinct what grid to refer to. Giving the grids different id's would work, but then the code in the script will return an undefined error on grid.selected().

Update:

So the solution of using

```
var grid = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

works to a certain point. It loads the data into the grid, but fails to do anything else. For example a part of my code for enabling an update and delete button doesn't work on the 2nd and 3rd partial view.

```
var grid = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selected = grid.select();
if (selected.length > 0) {
    $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
} else {
    $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").addClass("k-state-disabled");
}
```

Somehow the code only starts working for grid 2 and 3 after i have selected a row on grid 1, which is not as intended.

Comment: Are you sure that button id on each partial page is same?

Comment: I checked just to be sure, but yes the names are the same on all partial views. Honestly i'm at the point where i'm considering making these partial views into seperate pages just because it won't work...

Comment: It turns out the problem was that .k-grid wasn't calling the correct table reliably. It would often call the first table while I was looking at the second or third one. A working solution is to save the grid i'm looking at into a variable within the script and use that to call the correct data. Unfortionately this would cause problems when multiple partial views are open in different browser tabs, but that's a problem for another day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found with help of a senior programmer is to save the grid data into a global variable like this.

```
var PartialGridData = PartialGridData || {};
```

After that I'm setting and changing the variable whenever changing the partial view.

```
PartialGridData.selectedGrid = $("#PartialGrid1").data("kendoGrid");
```

Where the name #PartialGrid1 is the name of the current grid.
This means I need to write this code as many times as I have grids, but it also fixes a lot of problems. After that I use it to select the correct data.

```
var grid = PartialGridData.selectedGrid;
var selected = grid.select();
if (selected.length > 0) {
    $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
} else {
    $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").addClass("k-state-disabled");
}
```

Another option would be to use e.sender.

```
function onRowSelect(e) {
    var grid = e.sender;
    var selected = grid.select();
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
    } else {
        $("#btnCopy,#btnEdit,#btnDelete").addClass("k-state-disabled");
    }
}
```

Both solutions have their drawbacks though. Not all methods get the variable e used for e.sender and changing partial views in a way that is not caught will cause the global variable not to be updated, so this has to be kept in check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id(#Grid) you can use class(.k-grid):

```
  var grid = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: After a LOT of trial and error, i have come to the conclusion that this doesn't in fact work as intended. It works for part of the methods that use it, but doesn't work for others. I'll include a bit more information in an update of the question